# Getting notified when CALayer draw is done

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

Is there any way to get notified when a certain CALayer's drawing operation (including sublayers' drawing) is done?

The reason I need this is that while my layer's frame is being resized and thus redrawn (expensive and slow), I want to display a temporary image snapshot which is scaled nicely to the new size to conceal the old content.  I thus want to know when to dismiss the image snapshot (rather than setting an arbitrary time delay).

Comment: What do you mean? If you have triggers the re-draw of the layer, couldn't you remove the temporary image at the end of the drawing operation? Otherwise, if you have to show a temporary image anyway, why don't you move the layer (but hide it) and animate another layer from the old size to the new size and then show the real layer when the animation is complete? Wouldn't that achieve the same effect?

Comment: What I mean is, the CALayer in question is a hierarchy/tree of sublayers (as with most layer objects).  It is up to Core Animation framework's internals to traverse this tree and send each sublayer in the tree a **drawInContext** message.  How do I know which sublayer is the last one to receive this message, so that I can do my stuff (i.e. hide temporary image) at the end of _that_ sublayer object's method?